# Get and Trim Full Post Content in WP Query

Tags: wp-query, post-content

Simple task, but it isn't working:

```
<?php 
$content = apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content() );
$contentWithoutHTML = wp_strip_all_tags($content);
$pos = strpos($contentWithoutHTML, " ", 100);
$contentFinal = substr($contentWithoutHTML,0,$pos ); 
echo $contentFinal . "...";
?>
```

My post is way over 100 characters long (with spaces), and yet I get `strpos(): Offset not contained in string` error, which leads me to believe it isn't actually pulling the entire content string. But I applied filters like I believe I should... please assist. Also sometimes even if I get no offset error I just get `...` even though again, over 100 characters with spaces... although sometimes it works. Why the inconsistency?

This is in a `WP_Query` loop in which most of them work, but some of them do not... so I am pretty sure it is being fed a string because I see it happening to the other posts in the loop...

Full Loop:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'orderby' => 'ID',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => 7,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => '_thumbnail_id'
        )
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
while ($query->have_posts()):
    $query->the_post();
?>
                            <div class="articleboxs boxs">
                                <div class="col-sm-4 noleft">
                                    <div class="aricleleft boxs">
                                      <?php the_post_thumbnail('medium', array(
        'class' => 'img-responsive'
    )) ?>  
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-8 noright">
                                    <div class="aricleright boxs">
                                        <div class="boxs">
                                             <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><h2 class="heading font_Libre"><?php the_title(); ?></h2></a>
                                                <?php
    $content = apply_filters('the_content', get_the_content('', true));
    print_r($content);
    $contentWithoutHTML = wp_strip_all_tags($content);
    $pos = strpos($contentWithoutHTML, " ", 100);
    $contentFinal = substr($contentWithoutHTML, 0, $pos);
?>
                                 <p class="font_Roboto"><?php echo $contentFinal . "..."; ?></p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                          <?php
endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best thing to do would be to just simplify what you're doing. I'd just do something simple with it if all you're attempting to do is trim the amount of characters output. I'd use `mb_strimwidth` to trim the characters, and within that run `wp_strip_all_tags()` on `get_the_content()`. Like this:

```
$content = mb_strimwidth(wp_strip_all_tags(get_the_content()), 0, 100, '...');
echo $content;
```

Edit: Forgot to note that if you're going to have shortcodes in your content, *which I highly recommend against*, you may also have to wrap `get_the_content()` with `strip_shortcodes()`.

Comment: My problem is that even `$content = apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content('', TRUE) );print_r($content);` doesn't print out the entire content for a handful of posts in my query...

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question lies in the role of

[`get_the_content()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_content/)

As it is now clear to me, this function is not designed to get the entirety of the post content in the loop, which is why part of the function talks about `$more_link_text` and `$strip_teaser` as arguments, in regards to the text that gets trimmed.

Furthermore, `apply_filters('the_content', get_the_content('', true))` doesn't solve this fundamental problem, it merely does some HTML changes to the content.

So instead in my loop, I reference the global `$post`.

`$post->post_content` and do the `strpos` and `substr` from there.

Basically, as I am doing my own trimming/excerpt functionality, I can bypass `get_the_content()` entirely. As I am also wanting to put it right into a `<p>` tag, my code can just look like this:

```
<?php 
$contentWithoutHTML = wp_strip_all_tags($post->post_content);
$pos = strpos($contentWithoutHTML, " ", 100);
$contentFinal = substr($contentWithoutHTML,0,$pos ); 
?>
<p class="font_Roboto"><?php echo $contentFinal . "..."; ?></p>
```

Don't forget to reset the `WP_Query` after so as to keep leveraging `$post` sucessfully, with `wp_reset_postdata();` after the loop.